# BFS Map-Drawing in C#

Tags: c#, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

How do I use BFS in an unweighted, undirected graph in C#, implemented using adj list to dye a map, using four colors so that 2 countries that are neighbours to have different colors.

This is how I implemented the graphs, I will add, an array that represents the four colors as strings, and another one for countries, such as every vertex to represent a country.

```
    internal class Graph
    {
        private int vertices;
        private LinkedList<int>[] adj;
        public Graph(int v)
        {
            vertices = v;
            adj = new LinkedList<int>[v];
            for(int i = 0; i < v; i++)
            {
                adj[i] = new LinkedList<int>();
            }
        }

        public void addEdge(int c, int v)
        {
            adj[c].AddLast(v);
        }

        public void BFS(int s)
        {
            bool[] visited = new bool[vertices];
            for(int i=0; i<vertices; i++)
            {
                visited[i] = false;
            }

            LinkedList<int> queue = new LinkedList<int>();

            visited[s] = true;
            queue.AddLast(s);

            while (queue.Any())
            {
                s = queue.First();

                Console.WriteLine(s + " ");

                LinkedList<int> list = adj[s];

                foreach(var val in list)
                {
                    if (!visited[val])
                    {
                        visited[val] = true;
                        queue.AddLast(val);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TrifIonut_MapDrawing
{
    internal class Graph
    {
        private int vertices;
        private LinkedList<int>[] adj;
        private string[] color;
        public Graph(int v)
        {
            vertices = v;
            adj = new LinkedList<int>[v];
            color = new string[v];
            for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
            {
                adj[i] = new LinkedList<int>();
                color[i] = "";
            }
            color[0] = "blue";
        }

        public void addEdge(int c, int v)
        {
            adj[c].AddLast(v);
        }

        public void BFS(int s)
        {
            bool[] visited = new bool[vertices];
            for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
            {
                visited[i] = false;
            }

            LinkedList<int> queue = new LinkedList<int>();

            visited[s] = true;
            queue.AddLast(s);

            while (queue.Any())
            {
                s = queue.First();



                queue.RemoveFirst();

                LinkedList<int> list = adj[s];

                void visitor()
                {
                    List<string> possibleColors = new List<string>{"blue", "green", "yellow", "red" };
                    foreach (var val in list)
                    {
                        if (visited[val])
                        {
                            for(int i=0; i<possibleColors.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (color[val] == possibleColors[i])
                                {
                                    possibleColors.RemoveAt(i);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    color[s] = possibleColors[0];
                }

                visitor();

                foreach (var val in list)
                {
                    if (!visited[val])
                    {
                        visited[val] = true;
                        queue.AddLast(val);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really know how to modify the BFS function to help me in my matters.

Comment: Forgot to add, all I need is a console application, that will write the countries, their neighbours and their colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a "visitor", which is a small function that is called each time a new node is reached in the search.  Pass into the visitor the index of the newly visited node.  In the visitor look at all the adjacent nodes of the new one.  If adjacent node has been visited, remove adjacent node's color from possible colors.  Color the new node with a color not being used by the visited adjacent nodes.

Comment: Like this? List<string> possibleColors = new List<string>{ "blue", "green", "yellow", "red" };
                    foreach (var val in list)
                    {
                        if (visited[val])
                        {
                            possibleColors.Remove(colors[val]);
                        }
                    }

                    return possibleColors.First();

Comment: Hard to make out code in comment.  You have to loop over adjacent nodes ONLY to the newly visited.  I doubt that foreach (var val in list)  does so.

Comment: Should the visitor method be in the BFS method? If not, how do I check the visited nodes? I edited the code to see the modifications I made so far.

Comment: It worked, but what I didn't realized is that I implemented a directed graph, and when I modified it, it worked.

Comment: The visitor method should be called by the search code when it visits a new node.  It can be located anywhere where the compiler can find it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really helped me.